# PDI 8.0 S3 CSV Input

Tags: amazon-s3, kettle, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I'm trying to connect to a S3 bucket using S3 CSV Input and got an error. I tried on 7.1 PDI version and worked fine, but on 8.0 PDI I couldn't even select a bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem in PDI 8.0, there is no resolution yet.